# What is the Date format for Activiti Rest Query?

Tags: rest, date, activiti

What is the appropriate date format for query in activiti-rest calls?
I keep getting the error below, and i have tried, different date formats.

```
{"errorMessage":"The given value for query-parameter 'startedAfter' is not a valid date: 2013-04-03T23:45Z","statusCode":400}
```

Below are the date formats i have tried:

```
startedAfter=2013-04-03T23:45Z
startedAfter=2009-01-08
startedAfter=2009-01-08T00:00:00+01:00
```

Comment: I got the solution. http://forums.activiti.org/content/rest-api-task-query-due-date-dueafter-duebefore-error      Accepted date format is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. 
On Activiti Forum: http://forums.activiti.org/content/rest-api-task-query-due-date-dueafter-duebefore-error 
Accepted date format is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
Thanks.

Comment: Accept your own ans as(if) it is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Example for the date format to be used is as below -
2020-09-02T16:42:11+05:30 for activiti 6